# Clean Architecture / Hexagonal I/O adapters how to devide them

Tags: clean-architecture

In many articles I read about Clean or Hexagonal Architecture and I found there informations about I/O Adapters but still in many projects i have found repository with save / get method as a one class, one adapter with one implemented port.

Why isn't that in two different ports?

For example:

- interface ProductOutput → with get methods
- interface ProductImput → with save methods

Answer (score 1):

Input Adapters are systems which can drive your "Hexagone" like IHMs, batches.

Output Adapters are systems driven by your "Hexagone" like databases, messaging systems.

Answer (score 0):

Juliens answer is correct, but ill try to go a bit deeper.

The main part of Hexagonal Architecture is Domain layer. This layer contains business rules - entities and services, but it should not contain any implementation detail, like repository which gets from and saves to PostgreSQL. Instead of this you put interface there and implementation to Infrastructure layer. It makes testing of domain layer easier, you can implement inmemory repositories for testing purposes.

Now this what Ive been writing about are ports and adapters. Driven adapters are implementation of "ports" - interfaces located in your domain layer.

Driving adapter calls your application/domain service - like http handler or cli command handler.